# a road from virial identity to Strichartz estimates for wave/ Schrodinger eqs?

Tags: wave-equation, strichartz-estimates

Is there any way how virial identity implies Strichartz estimates ( or  some smoothing properties) for solutions to  a) wave equation b) Schrodinger equation ( say in 3d)? To keep things clear I am interested in the most simple linear case. Or may be someone knows where I can read about this?